# Custom Post Type link

Tags: wordpress

Hello I'm trying to get the following code to link to the associated post in a WordPress theme. I want the carousel title to go to the correct post. I have a custom query that is using a tag of slide to add posts to the carousel. I have tried different variations of the follow code and for some reason I can only get the link in the Carousel caption to return the homepage of the theme. If someone could point me in the right direction to get the post title to link back to the post I would appreciate the help.

This is my code. What am I missing?

```
    <?php
    $slides = array(); 
$args = array( 'tag' => 'slide', 'nopaging'=>true, 'posts_per_page'=>5 );
$slider_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) {
        $slider_query->the_post();
        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
            $temp = array();
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
            $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
            $temp['title'] = get_the_title();
            $temp['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
            $temp['image'] = $thumb_url;
            $slides[] = $temp;
        }
    }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php if(count($slides) > 0) { ?>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel-slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php for($i=0;$i<count($slides);$i++) { ?>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i==0) { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ol>


        <?php $i=0; foreach($slides as $slide) { extract($slide); ?>
        <div class="item <?php if($i == 0) { ?>active<?php } ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>">
            <div class="carousel-caption"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><p><?php echo $excerpt; ?></p></div>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the permalink of a custom post type you can use `get_post_permalink($id)`.

If you're using it inside The Loop use `get_permalink()` instead.

[get_post_permalink() documentation:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/)

> `get_post_permalink( int $id, bool $leavename = false, bool $sample = false )`
>
> Retrieves the permalink for a post of a custom post type.

[get_permalink() documentation:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)

> get_permalink( int|WP_Post $post, bool $leavename = false )
>
> Retrieves the full permalink for the current post or post ID.

Comment: No problem. Please select my answer as correct if it helped.